# How to generate multiple dataframes from a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary like the following

```
dict = {“df_text":df1, “df_logo":df2, “df_person":df3}
```

Each of the values in the dictionary is a dataframe.
Yet my actual dictionary is larger, so I want to make a loop that generate multiple dataframes from all of the components of this dict. In a way that “key” be the name of the dataframe and the corresponding value the dataframe’s value.

ex.
df_text=pd.DataFrame(df1)

How can I do this?

Comment: The best way is to create no dataframe an use the ones that are already in the dictionary if you want to access it just do dict["df_text"]

Comment: @DaniMesejo Thanx, however for the sake of my codes that comes after this part in the script I need to save each of them under a name.

Comment: if `df1` is already a dataframe, as you write, then why do you want to do `= pd.DataFrame(df1)`?

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. I need to have df_text=df1, df_logo=df2 and df_person=df3 , I will use df_text and other two(in this example) dataframes later for modeling. Maybe there are other ways but my python knowledge is limited and I need dataframes to work on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the contents of your dict as variables to [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars):

```
for k, v in dict.items():
    vars()[k] = v
```

After that you can access them simply as `df_text`, `df_logo` etc.

(as you wrote in your question, the values of your dict are already dataframe, so I assume you don't want to wrap them once more into a dataframe)

Comment: I didn’t understand how it is possible to access df_text for example, can you explain a little more. thank you

Comment: You can use them as any other varible, just be typing `df_text`, e.g. `print(df_text)`. Have a look at the linked docs for `vars`.